# Android Buttons have an undesired margin

Tags: android, android-layout, button, margin

I wrote a test application to describe my problem better. I started a new Android project with this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.jannevers.myapplication.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the first problem is, the button does not really fill the parent, it has a margin (see screenshot):

[image]

I can work around this, by making the button bigger than it should be.

But then the second problem is, that the margin is the same on the most devices, but not all. E.G. at a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge, there is almost no margin (see screenshot):

[image]

This is really weird, anyone know a solution?

Comment: you can try to override the `android:margin="0"` in your relative layout.

Comment: does not change anything

Comment: The layout is inside a fragment or an activity?

Comment: its not a margin and its not a padding inside the button, you can easily replicate the issue, and clearly the button fulfills the layout but the button image doesn't fulfill the button view, some may say it's because of the built in shadow of the button or whatever, - however you can use a custom 9patch background for your button and it will fulfill the view.

Comment: yes, the button fulfills the layout, margin was not really the right word. Hm I would like to use the standard background with its pressed states, but maybe using custom backgorund is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Use `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"`

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>
```

Comment: hm no, i do not want a borderless button. The button shall have borders, but not with a "margin"

Comment: @SJ.Doe that space is not a margin. its shadow of borders. you can create border of button.

Comment: dont really get what you mean. i know it is not a margin, it is a transparent area in the background of the button. The problem is, it is different on some devices and that is really crappy because the size of the visible button changes then.

Answer (score 0):

Check if into your style.xml there is a rule about layout margin like this:

```
<item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
```

Comment: no, it is a new android studio project. styles.xml only contains AppTheme with colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark, colorAccent